# Radio button should open new activity, only when edittext field is not empty

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, textwatcher

I want to check if my `EditText` is empty, and only if it is not it should open the second activity, upon clicking any of the two radio buttons:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private boolean flag=true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        radioGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        start();
    }

    public void start(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, contacts.class);
        name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                if(s.toString().length()!=0) {

                    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);

                            if (checkedId != -1) {
                                if (rb.getText() == "custom") {
                                    intent.putExtra("FLAG", flag);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                } else {
                                    flag = false;
                                    intent.putExtra("FLAG", flag);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Please type your name", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want the radiobuttons to redirect to the second activity only when the textfield is not empty. But it turns out that even when my text field is empty, the radiobuttons still redirect to the second activity

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the string `" "` is not an empty string. It is a string of a "space". You should use `""` instead in this line of your code:

```
if (!name.getText().toString().equals(" ")) {
```

By changing `" "` to `""` in this line, it should probably start working.